# If $P(A)=P(B)=1$, then $P(A\cap B)=1$

Tags: probability, solution-verification

This is my reasoning:

Using the probability law that

$$P(A \cup  B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$$

Since $P(A)+P(B) = 1$, and we know that the total probability cannot be greater than $1$. So, I can say that $P(A\cap B)$ must be equal to $1$.

Am I correct?

Comment: If $P(A) = P(B) = 1$, then $P(A)+P(B) = 2$, not 1.

Comment: Yes. You are absolutely right.

Answer (score 2):

Yup.

We have $$P(A\cup B) + P(A \cap B)=2$$

Hence, we must have $P(A \cup B)=P(A \cap B)=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is correct. I believe it is essential to understand the meaning of two events having probability 1.

If $ P(A)= 1 $ , then the probability of any event other than A is $0$. 
So there cannot exist an event B such that $P(B)=1$, unless the events A and B are the same events.

Since $A$ and $B$ are the same events, then $ P(A \bigcup B)= P(A) = P(B) =1 $.

Now, applying the rule $ P( A \bigcap B)  = P(A) + P(B) - P( A \bigcup B) $, then

$ P( A \bigcap B) = 1+1-1 $

Hence $ P( A \bigcap B) =1 $

Comment: They don't have to be the same event. Consider picking a random real number uniformly from $[0,1]$. Then the events "The number is irrational" and "The number isn't $\frac1\pi$" both have probability $1$, but they clearly aren't the same.